# The hypertriangular function of $n$

Tags: nt.number-theory, reference-request, sums-of-squares, closed-form-expressions

I'm looking for papers or recent results on the [hypertriangular function of $n$](http://ijpam.eu/contents/2007-36-2/9/9.pdf):

$$H_t(n)= \displaystyle\sum\limits_{k=1}^{n} k^k$$

This is [A001923 in the OEIS](http://oeis.org/A001923).

---

I don't have much experience with sums like this, but what makes finding a closed form so much more difficult that similar-looking sums such as the ones that appear in the ["Sophomore's dream" identities](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sophomore%27s_dream)?

Comment: A minor comment: in the Sophomore's dream identities one has series over $k^{-k}$ and not finite sums with general term $k^{k}$. The presence of a series allows you to relate the forms $x^{x}$ and $x^{-x}$ to the Taylor series of an exponential function (look at the first proof in the wikipedia page from the bottom to the top). In the OP one has simply a polynomial, instead.